# Specified directory is not created in Path

Tags: excel, vba, directory

```
Option Explicit

Private log As Object
Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr
#If VBA7 Then
 Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
 Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds as Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If

'===================================== Log ====================================
Public Sub initLog()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim sLogName As String
    Dim sLogPath As String
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sLogPath = "C:\Users\" & UserName & "\Documents\Tmp\xlLog"
    sLogName = "\Metric-Log.txt"
    If Not FSO.FolderExists(sLogPath) Then
        MkDir sLogPath
        If Dir(sLogPath & sLogName) <> "" Then
            Set log = FSO.OpenTextFile(sLogPath & sLogName, 8, 0)
        Else
            Set log = FSO.CreateTextFile(sLogPath & sLogName, False)
        End If
    End If
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

`UserName` is defined elsewhere. `\Tmp\xlLog` is not being created though. The code does compile and run past this function but, when looking in File Explorer, no folder with the name indicated in `sLogPath`is shown.

Comment: Have you checked if MkDir can make new folders with subdirectories? Also the reason it doesn't fail is because you have `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Got a run time error stating the path didn't exist and noticed it wasn't creating the directory ```\Tmp``` and ```xlLog```. After removing ```\Tmp``` from ```sLogPath``` it created the directory. Thank you @JeremyThompson Should post your comment as an answer so it can be marked as resolved/answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked `on Error Resume Next`, as pointed out by @JeremyThompson. That helped me realize that I couldn't create 2 folders on one `MkDir` command. That solved the problem.